# Bootstrap Photo gallery: responsiveness on desktop has bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, desktop, image-gallery

Every time the window is sized from big:

http://res.cloudinary.com/liberationfront/image/upload/v1497626018/vb1_t29xlz.png

To small:

https://res.cloudinary.com/liberationfront/image/upload/v1497625905/vb2_gtmjrl.png

There is all of a sudden a gap.

Comment: I tryed putting a bootstrap grid in fiddle but it didnt really work. So i made a example on bootply.

https://www.bootply.com/AUzqSaj1cg

Comment: Here is the original http://mos-man.be/

Comment: I tryed inspecting, but no clue why there is a bug.

Comment: Please update your post with new information rather than creating a stack of comments. And the requirements at SO are that your code sample is in your post, not just at another website.

Comment: Thank you for the guidelines. I was being creative, because I  still have low reputation I can't put more than 2 references in one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that your images don't all have the exact same aspect ratio, so some of them end up a pixel taller than others in some cases. Then the floated columns don't clear properly.

You can either re-crop your images, which is a fragile solution since you then rely on all future images being perfectly cropped, or you can set your cards' height through CSS and let the images flow to fit. Often using background images gives much more flexibility.

I suggest looking into [Bootstrap's responsive embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) and setting your images as backgrounds on a child element. Create your own 1:1 class if needed.

Comment: I cropped them, but not perfect. Makes sense now.